# Address of malloc'ed array passed to function - seg fault

Tags: c, pointers

I have a `malloc`ed array, and I need to pass its address to another function so that it can manipulate it. However, it looks like my C is rusty.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int **ints)
{
    printf("%d\n", *ints[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int *ints = malloc(3);
    ints[0] = 's';
    ints[1] = 't';
    ints[2] = 'a';
    f(&ints);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `*ints[1] == *(ints[1]) != (*ints)[1]`... Basic operator precedence. (I'd have expected something better from someone with near 15k rep...)

Comment: @H2CO3 my rep doesn't mean I'm very versed in C :)

Comment: Unless you plan to change `ints` itself (i.e., the address pointing to the allocated memory), there really is no reason to pass `&ints`. Just change `f` to `f(int *ints)` and access `ints[1]` etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) You just have the operator precedence wrong (`[]` for array subscripts has higher precedence than `*` for pointer dereference). Add an extra set of parentheses, and you should be fine:

```
printf("%d\n", (*ints)[1]);
```

2) You're allocating 3 bytes of memory instead of `3 * sizeof(int)` (hat tip:alk):

```
int *ints = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Aaaaand the reason for downvoting this correct answer is: ... ?

Answer (score 5):

To allocate memory for an `int` allocate `sizeof(int)`, to have room for 3 `int`s do:

```
int * ints = malloc(3 * sizeof(*ints)); /* 3 times the size of what ints points to. */
```

And if you do not have the need to manipulate the value of `ints` itself you could pass the array directly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int * ints)
{
  printf("%d\n", ints[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
  int * ints = malloc(3 * sizeof(*ints));
  ints[0] = 's';
  ints[1] = 't';
  ints[2] = 'a';

  f(ints);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Ok, for completeness:

In case you really need to pass down the address of `ints` (as per your example), then be aware that the `[]` operator binds tighter than the `*` operator and do:

```
void f(int ** pints)
{
  printf("%d\n", (*pints)[1]);
}
```

---

Also it is a good idea to pass the number of the elements of the array along, as it is not determinable from the pointer received by the function, like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int * ints, size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    printf("ints[%zu] = %d\n", i, ints[i]);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int * ints = malloc(3 * sizeof(*ints));
  ints[0] = 's';
  ints[1] = 't';
  ints[2] = 'a';

  f(ints, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making this a more comprehensive answer. Since your answer doesn't focus on the issue I had, I'll accept godel9's answer. The only issue I had was the operator precedence, other stuff was just there to keep the example minimal. Thanks for mentioning it though!

Comment: @haccks: I love the centered `*`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
printf("%d\n", (*ints)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to godel9's answer, you don't need to pass the address of the variable storing the address of the array; you just need to pass the address of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int *ints)
{
    printf("%d\n", ints[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int *ints = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    ints[0] = 's';
    ints[1] = 't';
    ints[2] = 'a';
    f(ints);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

`&ints` gives the address of the 4/8 bytes of memory on the stack that represent the `int *ints` variable.

Edit:
I've made edits to fix the allocation size as per godel9/alk's answer.I was focusing on reference count :)

Comment: Good point... Passing in the address of `ints` isn't necessary in the example given.

Comment: Well double pointers have their use. If you have an un-initialized variable that you want some other function to initialize for you, pass a reference to that variable to the function like you had originally done. I find this handy when I have functions that want to return two pieces of information and I don't want to create a struct to hold them, like `BOOL FindItem(ItemType &foundItem)` or `BOOL FindItems( ItemType** foundItems)`.

Comment: Ah! Indeed, that's what I do somewhere else in my code. That's why I just used this again :-)